# Need an optimized xpath expression to get the desired nodesets

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0, xpath-1.0

I do have a sample `XML` file :-

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<bookstore>
  <book>
     <title>The Weather Pattern</title>
     <author>Weather Man</author>
     <price>100.00</price>
  </book>
  <book>
     <title>Weaving Patterns</title>
     <author>Weaver</author>
     <price>150.00</price>
  </book>
  <book>
     <title>Speech Pattern</title>
     <author>Speaker</author>
     <price>15.00</price>
  </book>
  <book>
     <title>Writing Style</title>
     <author>Writer</author>
     <price>1500.00</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

I write the **XPATH** expression as:

```
//author[starts-with(text(),'We')]/../*[local-name(.) = 'price' or local-name(.) = 'author']/text()
```

**Output**

```
Weather Man
100.00
Weaver
150.00
```

I am looking for a modified,simplified xpath expressions to get the same output. Different thought is also welcome.Any help?

Comment: Can any one edit this post to have the syntax highlighting effect please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a modified XPath expression. It gives the same output. Simplicity is in the eyes of the beholder.

```
//book[starts-with(author, "We")]/*[not(local-name(.)="price")]/text()
```

Or, without `local-name`, which makes sense only if different namespaces are involved:

```
//book[starts-with(author, 'We')]/*[self::author or self::title]/text()
//book[starts-with(author, 'We')]/*[not(self::price)]/text()
```

Comment: WoowW... Very cool.. why I didn't think this? :) still *+1*.. Thank you very much..

Comment: Any more idea to do the same task *Sir* ?